# How to pass bool argument to fabric command

Tags: python, boolean, fabric

Currently I'm using `fab -f check_remote.py func:"arg1","arg2"...` to run fab remote.

Now I need to send a bool arg, but True/False become a string arg, how to set it as bool type?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [fabric docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/usage/fab.html#task-arguments), all the arguments end up as strings. The simplest thing to do here would just check the argument:

```
def myfunc(arg1, arg2):
  arg1 = (arg1 == 'True')
```

The parentheses aren't required, but help with readability.

**Edit**: Apparently I didn't actually try my previous answer; updated. (Two years later.)

Comment: But anyway if you send True or False as parameter when executing any task it will evaluate to True, because bool('True') evaluates to True as bool('False') does. A better better solution could be just not sending the parameter or set to False the variable if the arg is equal to 'False'

Comment: As the previous comment states, this answer cannot be accepted, since it does not work, or at least misleading. The bool results will be True for any string

Answer (score 40):

I'm using this:

```
from distutils.util import strtobool

def func(arg1="default", arg2=False):
    if arg2:
        arg2 = bool(strtobool(arg2))
```

So far works for me.
it will parse values (ignoring case):

```
'y', 'yes', 't', 'true', 'on', '1'
'n', 'no', 'f', 'false', 'off', '0'
```

strtobool returns 0 or 1 that's why bool is needed to convert to True/False boolean.

For completeness, here's `strtobool`'s implementation:

```
def strtobool (val):
    """Convert a string representation of truth to true (1) or false (0).

    True values are 'y', 'yes', 't', 'true', 'on', and '1'; false values
    are 'n', 'no', 'f', 'false', 'off', and '0'.  Raises ValueError if
    'val' is anything else.
    """
    val = val.lower()
    if val in ('y', 'yes', 't', 'true', 'on', '1'):
        return 1
    elif val in ('n', 'no', 'f', 'false', 'off', '0'):
        return 0
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid truth value %r" % (val,))
```

Slightly better version (thanks for comments mVChr)

```
from distutils.util import strtobool

def _prep_bool_arg(arg): 
    return bool(strtobool(str(arg)))

def func(arg1="default", arg2=False):
    arg2 = _prep_bool_arg(arg2)
```

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer. It's a shame that strtobool doesn't actually return a `bool` - it returns an `int`!

Comment: I **think** this statement covers all bases nicely: `arg2 = True if arg2 == 'arg2' else bool(strtobool(str(arg2)))` - then you can do `fab func:arg2=True`, `fab func:arg2=1` or simply `fab func:arg2` to switch it on, and `fab fun:arg2=False`, `fab func:arg2=0` or `fab func` to switch it off.  The innermost `str()` means you can avoid the `if arg2:` check and really get a one-liner (as it converts the default value of `False` to string `"False"` before passing it to `strtobool()`).

Comment: Thanks! I made a variant on this so you don't have to do the `if` check: `_prep_arg(arg): return bool(strtobool(str(arg)))` then just `arg2 = _prep_arg(arg2)`

Comment: @gimboland That would be ok if you retain order of parameters and always provide first one. In this example if you do: fab func:arg2 it will actually give arg1 value 'arg2' and keep arg2 False so not necessary what you had in mind probably

Answer (score 14):

I would use a function:

```
def booleanize(value):
    """Return value as a boolean."""

    true_values = ("yes", "true", "1")
    false_values = ("no", "false", "0")

    if isinstance(value, bool):
        return value

    if value.lower() in true_values:
        return True

    elif value.lower() in false_values:
        return False

    raise TypeError("Cannot booleanize ambiguous value '%s'" % value)
```

Then in the task:

```
@task
def mytask(arg):
    arg = booleanize(arg)
```

Answer (score 5):

If the func in question uses "if argN:" instead of "if argN is True:" to test if a boolean value is true, you could use "" for False and "anything" for True.

See also: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: `arg1` would evaluate to `True` when equal to `"False"`, which would be quite unintuitive.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the pattern consistently ('false','true' is boolean) on all your tasks, you can just wrap fabric task and apply it on all

You can use this package (written by me): https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boolfab/

Here is (essentially) the source:

```
from fabric.api import task as _task

def fix_boolean(f):
    def fix_bool(value):
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            if value.lower() == 'false':
                return False
            if value.lower() == 'true':
                return True
        return value

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        args_ = [fix_bool(arg) for arg in args]
        kwargs_ = {k: fix_bool(v) for k,v in kwargs.iteritems()}
        return f(*args_, **kwargs_)

    return wrapper


def task(f):
    return _task(fix_boolean(f))
```

So that it becomes:

```
@task
def my_task(flag_a, flag_b, flag_c)
   if flag_a:
       ....
```

without polluting each task with 'booleanizing' args.

Comment: This breaks `@task(name='foo-bar')` or `@task(default=True)`.

Comment: Here's a fixed version (untested): https://gist.github.com/mgedmin/f832eed2ac0f3ce31edf

Answer (score 3):

A better way would be to use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

def my_task(flag):
    if isinstance(flag, basestring): # also supports calling from other tasks
        flag = literal_eval(flag)
```

Although this doesn't take into consideration values like 'yes' or 'no', it is slightly cleaner and safer than `eval`...

Answer (score 1):

Craig and Ari's answers will result in a True value if the user passes "False" (Ari's answer is clearer about this)

If you use eval() the strings "True" and "False" will evaluate to their correct boolean values, but if you're using default values you'll need to make sure they're strings and not Booleans.

```
def myfunc(arg1="True", arg2=False):
    arg1 = eval(arg1)
    arg2 = eval(arg2) #error
```

Comment: It's dangerous to eval user input.

Comment: Assuming this is in a developer environment, then if they want to destroy their own code base / server there are much easier ways of doing so.  Silly to have the answer downvoted so much.

Answer (score 1):

In my fabfiles I just do:

```
TRUTHY = [True, 1, '1', 'true', 't', 'yes', 'y']

@task
def my_task(my_arg=True):
    if my_arg in TRUTHY:
         # do stuff
    else:
         # do other stuff
```

Of course, this means any value not in TRUTHY is effectively `False`, but so far I haven't needed anything more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this using decorators. I like the flexibility and explicitness you get from using a decorator.

Here is the meat of the code:

```
import ast
from fabric import utils
from fabric.api import task
from functools import wraps


def params(*types, **kwtypes):
    def decorator(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            new_args = ()
            for index, arg in enumerate(args):
                new_args += __cast(arg, types[index]),
            for kwarg in kwargs:
                kwargs[kwarg] = __cast(kwargs[kwarg], kwtypes[kwarg])
            return function(*new_args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


def __evaluate(arg):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(arg)
    except:
        return str(arg)


def __cast(arg, arg_type):
    try:
        return arg_type(__evaluate(arg))
    except:
        utils.abort("Unable to cast '{}' to {}".format(arg, arg_type))
```

Here is what it looks like to use it in code:

```
@task
@params(int, bool, arg1=int, arg2=bool)
def test(arg1, arg2):
    print type(arg1), arg1
    print type(arg2), arg2
```

Here is what it looks like to call it via fab with good params:

```
fab test:0.1,1
<type 'int'> 0
<type 'bool'> True

fab test:5,arg2=False
<type 'int'> 5
<type 'bool'> False

fab test:arg1=0,arg2=false
<type 'int'> 5
<type 'bool'> True
```

**NOTE:** In the last example, "false" is True, this is expected behavior in python, however it may be naturally counter intuitive. Similar with passing False as an int, it will cast to 0 as int(False) == 0 in python

Here is what it looks like to call it via fab with bad params:

```
fab test:Test,False
Fatal error: Unable to cast 'Test' to <type 'int'>

Aborting.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version based on https://gist.github.com/mgedmin/f832eed2ac0f3ce31edf. Unlike the old version this actually honors all possible decorator parameters and the task alias(es):

```
from functools import wraps
from fabric import tasks

def fix_boolean(f):

    true_values = ("yes", "true", "1")
    false_values = ("no", "false", "0")

    def fix_bool(value):
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            if value.lower() in false_values:
                return False
            if value.lower() in true_values:
                return True
        return value

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        args_ = [fix_bool(arg) for arg in args]
        kwargs_ = {k: fix_bool(v) for k,v in kwargs.iteritems()}
        return f(*args_, **kwargs_)

    return wrapper


def task(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    The fabric.decorators.task decorator which automatically converts command line task arguments
    to a boolean representation if applicable.
    :param args:
    :param kwargs:
    :return: wrapped
    """
    invoked = bool(not args or kwargs)
    task_class = kwargs.pop("task_class", tasks.WrappedCallableTask)

    def wrapper(f):
        return task_class(fix_boolean(f), *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper if invoked else wrapper(args[0])
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/eltismerino/a8ec8584034c8a7d087e